# Issue while querying MySQL Database with Pomelo Entity Framework Core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I've a problem with the `dotnet core` and `Pomelo Entity Framework`. I'm using ASP.Net Core v1.1 and a MySQL database. The database that I'm using is the `employees` database, the example in the site of MySQL.

Here is the github repository of my project: https://github.com/raffaelecalza/employees

I'm developing a simple web app that queries some tables of the database and shows the data in some pages.
I used the `ef scaffolding` command to create models and dbContext classes.

The problem is that when the app has to render the `employees` data, it seems blocked and doesn't reply anything. This problem occurs only with the `employees` table because if I try to visit the `departments` page, everything goes right and the page is rendered with all the rows of the table.

Is there someone who can help me with?

Comment: Please avoid referring to code hosted on external websites and provide a minimal reproducible code or the relevant code pieces in your answer. Code on external sites can a) change and b) become unreachable (when you delete the GitHub repository for example) and then the answer becomes useless for future visitors who look for a similar problem

Comment: Ok I post code pieces in the question but can you help me? This is a school homework and I should complete it for the next week

Comment: Provide more information, like code of your razor view and the action that queries it. How many entries are in the database etc.

Comment: All informations are in the github repo... there are a lot of rows of code to paste here... Should I post here all pieces of code?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your project and applied `Migration` to create database and tables in my MySQL server using these two commands as I dont have your SQL scripts with data:

`Add-Migration <NAME>` 
`Update-Database`

Then I added sample data to `employees` table as shown from below `select` query:

```
MariaDB [employees]> select * from employees;
+--------+------------+------------+--------+------------+-----------+
| emp_no | birth_date | first_name | gender | hire_date  | last_name |
+--------+------------+------------+--------+------------+-----------+
|      1 | 2017-04-24 | John       | M      | 2017-04-24 | Smith     |
+--------+------------+------------+--------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

After inserting dummy data, I ran your project and I was able to browse employees index page and was able to retrieve data back in `UI`. I don't see any problem with your code as I was able to retrieve information back. For your information please see below screenshot:

[image]
It would be helpful if you can share more information. We can't see what you are seeing. So please add more information as others have requested. Or else this question shall be closed for lack of information.

Comment: Thank you!! I understand where was the problem.. The rendering was staying in loop because in the table of employees were more than 30000 rows so it toke a lot of time to build the page. I try with only 100 rows and it works perfectly.